# ER diagrams for databases (entity, attribute, etc) and examples of each

Tags: sql, entity-relationship

I have an introduction course to databases and have been issued a very simple assignment through which the goal is to become familiar with the parlance of SQL databases.

For example, by definition of an `entity`, I was asked to define which of a list of objects fit into this category (i.e. which were entities and which were attributes, etc). The only one that stumped me was the object: `Courses Used In` a specific book that someone might read.

My first though was that this is certainly an entity because it is distinctly identifiable through attributes such as class size, skill required, contact-hour, etc. However, I was not completely confident - but the logic seems correct.

And the second part that I was a bit confused on was with regards to constructing an ER diagram given an English description of what is needed. The description was as follows:

***Draw an entity representation for the entity “building” with the attributes building name, occupancy, and whether or not it has an elevator (yes/no). Embellish the building entity to include the building superintendent’s name (first, middle, last). Add a multi-valued attribute to the building entity.***

The solution I resolved looks like this:

[image]

A extension of the same problem reads the follows:

***Again, embellish the building entity to include names (and only names) of the janitorial staff***

Since the superintendent IS a member of the janitorial staff, I thought maybe I should add in a `Janitor Staff` attribute through which the `superintendant` would be connected - along with other `Janitors`.

However, I ended up doing this because not every Janitor in Janitor Staff would be a superintendent.

Any thoughts?

[image]

Comment: Regarding attributes versus entities: I feel that this is really up to the designer to determine. For instance, is a phone number an attribute or an entity? Could be both. If an entity, then the area code, prefix, and final four numbers are attributes. The same could be said for a color. If it's an entity, then its red, green, and blue components are the attributes.

Answer (score 3):

### Flaw

One possible flaw: I'm guessing that "Janitor Staff" should be a double-circle if that means one-or-more instances assigned. You may be conflating the collection of staff with the notion of individual persons. A better name for that entity/table might be "Janitor" or "Janitor Person" with a double-circle noting that you can have more than one staff person. The staff (the collection) is all of those "Janitor Person" instances. So the word/concept of "staff" need not appear. Saying you can have more than one instance is indeed saying you can have a collection.

To reiterate… Attributes for "Janitor Person" might be Name, Phone, EmployeeID, Photo. Those are attributes for each instance of a janitor person, obviously. Each person has only one name and one photo (ID badge mugshot) so single circles on them, but double-circle on "Janitor Person".

If I were standing next to you and discussing this chart, I might point to the "Janitor Person" double-circle and say the word "staff" while talking. But I wouldn't really mean that literally. In contrast, if a diagram actually had a double-circle with the word "Staff" that would mean we are representing a collection of staff people as a whole, and that we have *multiple groups* of these people. This could be the case in a business scenario. Imagine a business with unionized workers, like a hotel. The housekeepers might all be one "Staff" instance (together), and the cooks and kitchen workers may be another "Staff" instance. Each instance would note their own particular (different) union organization that represents that "Staff".

### Crow's Foot

I'm not familiar with that diagramming technique. I prefer the UML-style boxes (entity/table name at top, attributes/columns listed below) connected by [Crow's Foot Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-relationship_diagram#Crow.27s_Foot_Notation.) (unusually good name for the IT industry!).

Here is my take on it, using my style. This diagram would double as a [relational database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database) table design as well as an [ERD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model).

The first diagram follows the question's description of tracking on a single superintendent. That represents a One-To-One relationship. If you can have a building without a currently assigned superintendent, then that line attached to "Superintendent" should be a Zero-Or-One sign rather than a One sign.

If you add the element of history, that is, if you wanted to track past and future superintendents as well as currently assigned superintendent, then we have a One-To-Many relationship. This situation is shown in the second diagram. The line is different, and two attributes added for tracking the start and stop of the person's assignment as superintendent.

[image: A pair of ERD table-design diagrams]

Comment: I was also confused with the notion of an entity having an entity. That is, Building having Janitor which further has the information you list. Can an attribute have an attribute, or at this point would it be considered an entity (i.e. Building -> BrickType, would could extend to something like Building -> BrickType -> Color, for example). Would BrickType in this instance be an attribute or an entity?

Comment: As the name says, Entities are on the same level as Relationhips, and Relationships connect Entities (refer to Chen notation in the wikipedia article above which is pretty comprehensive). Chen's idea was, that not only natural languaged entities (Bulding, Janitor, Name) can have attributes, but also their Relationhips (Building has 3 Janitors since bla bla). The notation for a relationship is a diamond. Double circles only note that an attribute appears multiple time in one entity (never used that, because you have to transform this into a relational model anyhow)

Comment: I would prefer Janitor and superintentend also as an entity, where superintentend has an "is-a" relationship with janitor, and each of both have a "has-a" relationship with building, where mulitplicity is one for superintentend and multiple for janitor. As the description states, names of janitorial staff could also be modeled as multi-valued attributes here (althought I do not understand why I should model it this way....telephone numbers is a better example for a multi-valued attribute)